# Undefined template argument for base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, nested

I am quite sure I have read the reason why the compiler cannot cope with this code somewhere on SO, but, after a few hours of searching, I still can't find it. Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class base
{
};

class derived : base<derived::myStruct>
{
public:
    struct myStruct
    {
    };
};

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the parser first tries to generate the `base<derived::myStruct>` specialization before parsing `derived`, and, thus, I get this error: "error C2065: 'myStruct' : undeclared identifier". As a silly trick, I noticed that VS2010 stops complaining if I pre-declare `struct myStruct;` just above `class derived`. In my opinion, `myStruct` should be bound inside `derived` and this code should throw the same error:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class base
{
};

struct myStruct;

class derived : base<derived::myStruct>
{
public:
    struct myStruct
    {
    };
};

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**: gcc-4.5.1 is able to [throw the expected error](http://ideone.com/GgMOxT), so, I guess the above is a bug in VS2010...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to declare `myStruct` outside of `derived`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class base
{
};

struct derived_myStruct
{
};

class derived : base<derived_myStruct>
{
public:
    typedef derived_myStruct myStruct;
};

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In more complex cases where `derived` is a template class, `derived_myStruct` would too be a template class, with the same template paramerters (or just a subset), and you would pass those through.

Comment: It looks like this is the best solution for this particular design issue in C++. I don't like not being able to nest related types, but it seems there's no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

`derived::myStruct` is simply an incomplete type at this point. Your second example should also not work, unfortunately the MSVC compiler accepts a lot of malformed template code. One work around is to use an intermediate class to make sure the type is complete:

```
template <typename T>
class base
{
};

class middle
{
public:
    struct myStruct
    {
    };
};

class derived : public middle, base<middle::myStruct>
{
};

int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What purpose that the middle class serve, why isn't there just myStruct (as I proposed in my answer)?

Comment: Ah, I see, you avoided a typedef. But using multiple inheritance just for that seems a little weird :)

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak: I thought it would keep the inheritance pattern also, but I'm not sure what this is for.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can only refer to names once they are defined. Since `derived` is clearly not, yet, defined when you refer to a class nested inside `derived` to define a base class, this cannot work. The exception for things being sort of declared after they are accessed is for function bodies of members defined within the class definition: these are treated as if they are actually defined after the class definition.

Comment: So, how would I get around this limitation? I definitely remember there was a proposed workaround, and the one I provided above, from my point of view, should not work at all.